# SAP B1 special character (hypen) different from SQL Server during query result

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I encountered an instance in SAP B1 during my query and I still don't figure out how it happened. There is an item code in Item Master Data that in Excel I see it as a (-) dash/hyphen, but even when selected it's not showing up. See image below,

[image: Hypen/dash do not appear when selected]

Also in SQL, if I execute this query (typed from keyboard)

```
SELECT * FROM OITM WHERE ItemCode='14-563'
```

No result is found, but if I copy the code from Excel and paste in the code part of the query it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OITM WHERE ItemCode='14563'
```

Then there's a correct result, the same thing happened in SAP B1 item master data search, if I type directly to item code field, no result, but if I paste the code from Excel then there's a result.

Have anyone encountered the same? Or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Have you checked the formatting of the cell in Excel? For example when I enter `14563` into a cell and apply a custom format of `##-###` to it then the cell displays `14-563` until I edit it.

Comment: Paste the item code into a text editor with a hex view (such as PsPad) and see if it's really a hyphen (ASCII code 2D/decimal 45). Could be a unicode character that looks similar to a hyphen.

Comment: @Daz I'll have that check. Btw I also noticed that if I do save as from the Excel file to Text Tab Delimited, the "hyphen/-" converts to underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue. During the Item Code setup in Item Master data, the user used the keyboard shortcut for the hyphen that is `ALT+0173`, the issue has been replicated also and have advised the user to not use keyboard shortcut just for the hyphen purposes.

Credits to @Daz